# How to hide Bootstrap column on some pages

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

i need to  hide "right" column in "md position" on some pages (login, registration,contacts...) 
and extend "main" to col-md-12.

my index.php

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">             
    <div id="main" class="col-md-9 col-xs-12">
      <jdoc:include type="component" />
    </div>
    <div id="right" class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
      <?php if($this->countModules('right')) : ?>
       <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" style="none" />
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please use descriptive question titles and not a list of tags.

Comment: will do next time sir !

Comment: If you're happy with one of the answers, don't forget to choose the best one and accept it with "accept" button next to the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

i think the easiest way is checking the option & view in template and act based on its value , for example :

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
if(in_array($app->input->get('view'), array('login', 'registration') && in_array($app->input->get('option') ,array('com_users')){
    echo ' <div id="main" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">';
}
else {
    echo ' <div id="main" class="col-md-9 col-xs-12">';
}
```

and similar check for right menu

also you can create menu for login & registration & ... and dont add any module in this menu for the position that you want to hide

then you can check in template if there is noting in that position simply make main div full page width

Answer (score 0):

There is also a CSS way. You can print the option and view (or also itemid to base selection on the selected menu item) from `$_GET` as classes of the `<html>` or `<body>` tags and then just hide what you want via CSS (`display: none`). As for extending the `#main` div to full width, you can just override the class on the `#main` when using this approach.

To show you an example, the CSS for hiding `#right` div and extending `#main` div could look like this (example for K2 component and posts' detail view, in your case just the html classes (`.com_k2` and .view-item) would be different):

```css
html.com_k2.view-item #right { display: none; }
html.com_k2.view-item #main.col-md-9 { width: 100% !important; }
```

The `!important` could not be needed, I'm not sure, would have to try it.